# Print string angularjs 2 ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

My code is this :

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        var user1 = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        var name, email, photoUrl, password, uid, emailVerified;
        if (user != null) {
          name = user1.displayName;
          email = user1.email;
          photoUrl = user1.photoURL;
          emailVerified = user1.emailVerified;
          uid = user1.uid;  // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use
          // this value to authenticate with your backend server, if
          // you have one. Use User.getToken() instead.
          console.log(email);
        }
      } else {
        console.log('no user');
      }
    });
```

console.log(email) prints me the email but in html

```
<h1>email: {{ email }}</h1>
```

don't print me nothing,why?I googled but nothing. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print in the html, the variable should be a class property.
In your component class, declare `email`.

```
@Component()
export class cmp{
email:any;
//...
//In your firebase call set in this.email
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=> {//use arrow function to make sure this is correct
  if (user) {
    let user1 = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    let name, photoUrl, password, uid, emailVerified;
    if (user != null) {
      name = user1.displayName;
      this.email = user1.email;//here
      photoUrl = user1.photoURL;
      emailVerified = user1.emailVerified;
      uid = user1.uid;  // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use
      // this value to authenticate with your backend server, if
      // you have one. Use User.getToken() instead.
      console.log(this.email);
    }
  } else {
    console.log('no user');
  }
});
```

Now, show in html

```
 {{email}}
```

Comment: You should use `let` instead of `var`. Find an explanation here at the wonderful [typescript documentation][1]


  [1]: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html

Comment: @niklas you are right..thanks.. but not really the reason why OP is getting the issue

Comment: I declare it email:any; I did this.email=user1.email but nothing. Console log print: test1@gmail.com , but {{email}} nothing

Comment: where is `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` called? can you add component and html code? did you use arrow function?

Comment: I'm newbie but it's not an arrow function, it's imported from firebase

Comment: `()=>{}` is arrow function.. use (user)=>{..} instead of function(user){..}.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: If I add the arrow I have errors, 3 errors, it said me that { espected then ; and ; in if eand else

Comment: check my answer.. also I wont be able to tell you without seeing the code. It looks like some syntax errors though..